# cURL not able to connect to a specific https site

Tags: php, curl, wget

I'm trying to curl or wget to a website, but after 5 minutes I got an error :
cURL error SSL read: errno -5961

From Linux Centos 7:

```
* About to connect() to es.gearbest.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 23.43.82.164...
* Connected to es.gearbest.com (23.43.82.164) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=*.gearbest.com,OU=IT,O=Shenzhen Globalegrow E-Commerce Co. Limited,L=Shenzhen,ST=GuangDong,C=CN
*       start date: Feb 09 00:00:00 2019 GMT
*       expire date: May 10 12:00:00 2020 GMT
*       common name: *.gearbest.com
*       issuer: CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US
> GET /flash-sale-56.html HTTP/1.1
Host: es.gearbest.com
Accept: */*

* SSL read: errno -5961
* Closing connection #0
curl: (56) SSL read: errno -5961
```

Same site from Windows 10:

```
*   Trying 184.25.45.38...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to es.gearbest.com (184.25.45.38) port 443 (#0)
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with es.gearbest.com port 443 (step 1/3)
* schannel: disabled server certificate revocation checks
* schannel: verifyhost setting prevents Schannel from comparing the supplied target name with the subject names in server certificates.
* schannel: sending initial handshake data: sending 171 bytes...
* schannel: sent initial handshake data: sent 171 bytes
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with es.gearbest.com port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: failed to receive handshake, need more data
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with es.gearbest.com port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 3356
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 3356 length 4096
* schannel: sending next handshake data: sending 126 bytes...
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with es.gearbest.com port 443 (step 2/3)
* schannel: encrypted data got 242
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 242 length 4096
* schannel: SSL/TLS handshake complete
* schannel: SSL/TLS connection with es.gearbest.com port 443 (step 3/3)
* schannel: stored credential handle in session cache
> GET /flash-sale-56.html HTTP/1.1
> Host: es.gearbest.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
>
* schannel: client wants to read 102400 bytes
* schannel: encdata_buffer resized 103424
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 103424
* schannel: Curl_read_plain returned CURLE_RECV_ERROR
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 103424
* schannel: encrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 103424
* schannel: decrypted data buffer: offset 0 length 4096
* schannel: schannel_recv cleanup
* Closing connection 0
* schannel: shutting down SSL/TLS connection with es.gearbest.com port 443
* Send failure: Connection was reset
* schannel: failed to send close msg: Failed sending data to the peer (bytes written: -1)
* schannel: clear security context handle
curl: (56) Send failure: Connection was reset
```

I have tried to increase MTU to 9000 but same error happens....
other https sites works well.

any idea?

Thanks

Comment: It could be the version of cURL you are using. You could upgrade to a version equal or newer than the one on the Windows computer (7.55.1). The default version on CentOS 7.x is cURL 7.29.0. This link provides a repo for newer cURL rpms https://www.rootlinks.net/2017/09/21/update-curl-7-29-to-7-55-on-centos-7-with-city-fan-repo/

Comment: I had recompiled the curl version to curl 7.67.0 and is the same error.... The site and page works for you?

Comment: I get a 403 Access Denied, but it doesn't time out. Using cURL version 7.55.1.

Comment: to that url : https://es.gearbest.com/flash-sale-56.html ?

Comment: Yes... https://pastebin.com/qfrEdB39

Comment: oh... then is client side fault... There are only few lines differents from your log and mine... ay ideas why my computers times out?
https://pastebin.com/rHy7LG71